# Programmatically extracting GoogleSheets gid using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have a use case where I access Covid-19 data via a GoogleSheet URL. When the file is fully loaded the gid appears. in this instance it's: 1576906596. After a day or two, the gid id changes, making the URL to break, unless you visit the site with the part of URL without edit#**gid=1576906596**
Currently, I am manually reading the gid after loading the file, but I am looking for a way to extract that and tag it automatically with the main part of the URL
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14quQPFErG-hlpsrNgYcX85vW7JMMK5X2vNZrafRcH8c/edit#**gid=1576906596**

```
gid = "1576906596"    # need to extract automatically
baseURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14quQPFErG-hlpsrNgYcX85vW7JMMK5X2vNZrafRcH8c/"
fullURL = baseURL + gid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the sheet ID (GID) from the Spreadsheet.
- The Spreadsheet is publicly shared.
- You want to achieve this using Python.

### Issue and workaround:

In your case, in order to retrieve the sheet ID (GID) from the publicly shared Spreadsheet, it is required to use the get method of Sheets API. And also, in the current stage, an API key is required to use the Sheets API v4. Sheets API v3 could be used without using the API key. But Sheets API v3 is shut down on September 30, 2020. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3) So I recommend to use Sheets API v4.

### Usage:

In order to use this workaround, please do the following flow.

#### 1. Retrieve API key.

Please check [this official document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=ja#get-the-api-key) for retrieving the API key.

#### 2. Sample script.

```
import requests

apiKey = "###"  # Please set your API key.

# Retrieve GID from Spreadsheet.
spreadsheetId = "14quQPFErG-hlpsrNgYcX85vW7JMMK5X2vNZrafRcH8c"  # This is the Spreadsheet ID of your Spreadsheet.
url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + "?fields=sheets.properties.sheetId&key=" + apiKey
res = requests.get(url).json()
gid = "edit#gid=" + str(res["sheets"][0]["properties"]["sheetId"])

baseURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14quQPFErG-hlpsrNgYcX85vW7JMMK5X2vNZrafRcH8c/"
fullURL = baseURL + gid
print(fullURL)
```

When above script is run for your Spreadsheet, `fullURL` is as follows.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14quQPFErG-hlpsrNgYcX85vW7JMMK5X2vNZrafRcH8c/edit#gid=596323848
```

### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: Thank you for such an excellent contribution that explains fully how it works and how to get it done. It solved my use case and I no longer have to grab the gid manually. I also liked the explanation you provided about API V3 and V4.  This is awesome!

Comment: @Pancani Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.